# PC not fully shutdown

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, shutdown, desktop-computer

I've PC of lenovo model m91p i5-2400 win-10-pro 64bit.

There is a very weird problem when I shut it down.

When I shut down via the regular way (start- shut-down) it shut down the PC but it leaves the power led on, and the only way I can shut it down completly is to press and hold for 7 sec.

[image]

But, in two cases, the PC is fully shut down (the power led turn off)-

1. I give a command of "shutdown -s" via the cmd.
2. When I shut down the windows have updates, so after the updates it fully shut down by itself.

This is a very weird problem and I realy have no idea what to do!

I'll be thankful for any kind of help...

Comment: Take a look at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System. What is the value of HiberbootEnabled? If this key is missing you can create it and set the value to "0"

Comment: Thanks. I try this and it didnt work. but I found the answer

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer...
I just went to settings, power management, and disable the fast boot-up.

Comment: I have the same problem on M91p and confirm that turning off "Fast Startup" (this is the official name of the feature) helps. PS: I have Windows installed in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

To Disable Hibernation:
The first step is to run the command prompt as administrator. In Windows 10, right click on the start menu and click "Command Prompt (Admin)".
Type in "powercfg.exe /h off" without the quotes and press enter.
Exit the command prompt.
Hibernation is now disabled.

Answer (score 0):

My Lenove Thinkcentre (i3 2120 on Intel H61M) is still not shutting down. And it has only Legacy Boot. UEFI is not available.
?
After every shut down: Push for 4 seconds on the powerbutton.

Anyone has a better workaround?

Comment: This is not an appropriate ANSWER to the question. It would be appropriate for a comment.

Answer (score -1):

The only really full solution seems to reinstall Windows with legacy boot instead UEFI.
With all the other options above Sleep, hibernate, wake on LAN do NOT work.
Fresh installation on legacy solved all issues for me.
Alternativly there are also some tools arround for migrating an existing installation from UEFI to legacy...